# Is there a more convenient way to create a NSIndexPath object?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

```
    NSIndexPath *index_path;
    NSUInteger   u_array[] = {0, 0, 0};                
    index_path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes : u_array length : 3];
```

The above creates a NSIndexPath with length == 3.  Is there any way to do the same with fewer statements ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is probably the best you can do:

```
NSUInteger u_array[] = {0, 0, 0}; 
NSIndexPath *index_path = [NSIndexPath indexPathWithIndexes:u_array length:3];
```

Comment: The reason I asked this was I tried to put "{0, 0, 0}" in place of u_array in the above's 2nd statement.  And the compiler wouldn't accept it even a type cast was used.  I was wondering if somebody else can do it.  Do you have an explanation as why it cannot be done ?

Comment: Yes: you can use curly braces in C to initialize or assign to an array, but by itself, a comma-separated list of items in curly braces isn't an array. Or, in other words, there's no such thing as an array literal in C.

Answer (score 3):

If you're talking about using it in a `UITableView`, there's the [UIKit addition](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/NSIndexPath_UIKitAdditions/Reference/Reference.html) `indexPathForRow:inSection:`

`+ (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRow:(NSInteger)row inSection:(NSInteger)section`

Here's how to use it:

```
NSIndexPath *myIndexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:3 inSection:4];
```

Comment: So it seems that for (length >= 3) we have to settle for at least 2 statements.

Comment: Are you using it to identify one place in a table view? Or for something else?

Comment: Actually I am planning to create some NSIndexPath constants for a drill down menu.

Answer (score 1):

Only if you are using iOS (you've tagged this [iphone](/questions/tagged/iphone) and [cocoa](/questions/tagged/cocoa), so not sure which) and you are only interested in a two-part index path (i.e. a table section and row) - if this is the case you can use `[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:inSection:]`. This is described in the NSIndexPath UIKit additions section of the documentation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I meant cocoa-touch, the tag has been corrected accordingly.